# Is there a way to use Docker inside of a Pod in a Kubernetes cluster with containerd on the nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I have a Kubernetes cluster running with containerd on the nodes. I don't have the ability to install things on the nodes.
My task now is to deploy a pod which can use docker commands inside, for examle a docker pull or push. So docker should work in the container even though it is not installed on the host system. So I can't just mount the docker socket because it doesn't exist on the host. Is there a possibility?

Comment: Did you try Docker-in-Docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker ?

Comment: I've thought about it too. However, this does not enable all docker functions. Mounting volumes etc. is not possible, for example

Comment: Of course you can mount volumes with docker-in-docker. Although those volumes are mounted from you DIND host perspective: don't expect to attach kubernetes secrets or PVC, unless you mount them first in that DIND sidecar.

Comment: Hi, if you have resolved your issue as per the above comments; please post the answer. So, that it will be useful for other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem with a dind container. This now runs as a second container in the pod. In order to be able to mount volumes, I mounted the corresponding volumes across both containers. Works without problems so far.

Comment: Do you mean that you solved it by running a container with `privileged: true`?

Comment: yes, the dind container runs with securityContext: privileged: true